# C# COM string is corrupted in C++ BSTR

Tags: c#, c++, com

I wrote a C# COM object which I call from my native C++ code.
The C# COM has a few functions and events.

I registered in the C++ to the events, and I called the C# object.
At some point the event is being invoked, sending C# string as a parameter into C++ BSTR, which is corrupted.

I tried everything I can think of, and looked all over :-(

Does anyone have any idea why the BSTR is corrupted ???

EDIT:
Important info:

1. It works on x64 bit, the error happens only on the x86 version.
2. The C# COM is compiled as ANY CPU. I tried to compile it as x86, but it did not make any difference.

CS code, calling the event:

```
// declaring the event and delegate
public delegate void on_start_delegate(string dict_param);
public event on_start_delegate on_start_click;

void on_start(mydictionary dictparams)
{
     string strparams = dictparams.ToString();

     Trace.WriteLine(strparams); // the string is fine

     if (on_start_click != null)
        on_start_click(strparams); // <--- Calling C++
}
```

The connection point class:

```
[Guid("0581E......")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface Iregistration_form_events
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void on_start_click(string dict_param);
}
```

In the C++, registering to the event:

```
BEGIN_SINK_MAP(registraion_form)
        SINK_ENTRY_INFO(SENSOR_REG_SINK_ID, __uuidof(namespace::Iregistration_form_events), 1, on_start_click, &on_start_click_info)
END_SINK_MAP()

_ATL_FUNC_INFO registraion_form::on_start_click_info = {CC_STDCALL, VT_EMPTY, 1, {VT_BSTR}};
```

The function that the BSTR gets corrupted:

```
void registration_form::on_start_click( BSTR params ) // <-- params get corrupted!
{

dictionary dictparams;

std::wstringstream ss;
ss << params;
ss >> dictparams;

// do more stuff...
}
```

Again, THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP!!!!

Comment: Ideas are unlikely without actual code snippets. `BSTR`s don't get damaged for no reason.

Comment: Please show us how you call the C# COM object. Also what make you say that the string is corrupted?What is the representation of the string in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It works on x64" is a strong hint that you have a calling convention mismatch.  x64 has only one calling convention, but x86 has several.

Make sure that your event handler is declared as stdcall.

Comment: It just has to be STDCALL. There is no check there and compiler would pass wrong function reference.

Comment: You're Right!!!! :-) I missed it...

I didn't know x64 has one calling convention...! :-)